Insert on conflict update not working correctly in postgres
I am using on conflict clause for insert query like this:
insert into "public"."tbl" ("id", "col1", "col2") values ($1, $2, $3) on conflict ("id") do update set "id" = $4,"col1" = $5,"col2" = $6 returning "id" 
and I am getting this error:
null value in column "col3" of relation "tbl" violates not-null constraint
which doesn't make sense, because even thos col3 has NOT NULL constraint, I am not passing it in the insert query at all, so Postgres should just take it from the existing record, which certainly does not have a null value.
Am I misunderstanding how conflict works? Do I need to pass all columns in the query? If so, there is not point in using insert .. on conflict because it does not provide any benefit compared to separate insert / update calls.

col3 is not even mentioned in your INSERT statement, so it can only be NULL.

You must pass col3 into insert which obviously cannot be NULL, your error is not about conflict.

To expand on that, OP is inserting NULL by default. The test for NULLness happens before PostgreSQL even checks for conglicts.

demo at db<>fiddle

If you're on PostgreSQL 15 or above, you can switch your upserts to a merge:
MERGE INTO "public"."tbl" t
USING (VALUES ($1, $2, $3)) AS s("id", "col1", "col2") 
ON s."id" = t."id"
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN--you can skip this entirely if you're only updating
  INSERT("id", "col1", "col2", "col3")
  VALUES(s."id", s."col1", s."col2", -1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET "id" = $4
            ,"col1" = $5
            ,"col2" = $6 
--RETURNING t."id";--only PostgreSQL v17

If you're on PostgreSQL 17, you can even keep the returning clause.
Pass a dummy value for each column with a not null constraint:
insert into "public"."tbl" ("id", "col1", "col2", "col3") 
values ($1, $2, $3, -1/*dummy*/) 
on conflict("id")do update 
set "id" = $4
   ,"col1" = $5
   ,"col2" = $6 
returning "id";


If your only intention is to update because you expect zero non-conflicting rows, use an actual update:
update "public"."tbl" as t
set "id" = $4
   ,"col1" = $5
   ,"col2" = $6 
from(values($1, $2, $3))AS s("id", "col1", "col2")
where t."id"=s."id"
returning t."id";



Your idea could actually work if you made the not null constraint deferrable, even if it was initially immediate because the earliest a deferrable is validated is at the end of a statement. From Why does PostgreSQL check a DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE constraint after each statement?

In case of constraint violation, the exception is raised

at the end of transaction if the constraint is deferrable initially deferred
at the end of statement if it's deferrable initially immediate
mid-statement if it's not deferrable. that's your case


Problem is, as of PostgreSQL 17 deferrability is not supported for not null:

Currently, only UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY, REFERENCES (foreign key), and EXCLUDE constraints are affected by this setting. NOT NULL and CHECK constraints are always checked immediately when a row is inserted or modified (not at the end of the statement).

And that answers why you got the error even though the violation shouldn't even be possible in the wider context of the statement: you didn't address/target col3 at all and it didn't have a default to fall back on, so insert made it a null, then immediately checked and found that's not allowed.
It never progressed far enough to reach id conflict resolution where the problem would go away.

This will also fail since there is no col3 in your query.

@FrankHeikens I attached two demos, both work fine. Both queries also do have col3. If you mean the merge source doesn't, it doesn't but it also doesn't need it.

@FrankHeikens The earlier version worked fine already but I added an explicit merge..when matched then insert() column list to make the col3 thing more visible. Considered making it even more obvious by adding an explicit col3=col3 in each of the update parts as well, but that's not just overly verbose, I figured it's also functionally inequivalent - it would fire update of col3 on tbl triggers the current code does not: demo.
